# How to get the play list of song in iphone programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch

How to get the play list of song currently playing in iphone programmatically?
I could use the following code to get the song's artist:

[currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]

I couldn't find the property for the song's playlist.

Answer (score 1):

MPMediaItems don't know what collections they're in. What you want is the current playback queue, which would be accessible through the `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]`
Unfortunately apple doesn't give access to this at this point.